# Extract data for bayesian meta analysis of survival data

Tags: bayesian, survival, meta-analysis

I want to do a meta-analysis of survival data using a bayesian framework (gemtc). In the package documentation the input needed are the responders and the exposure in person-time for each arm of a study.

How can i calculate these data from published studies? Are the responders the percentage of person alive at a certain time point? How do I deal with censored data when calculating person-time?

Comment: From your description it sounds more like a study of incidence rates where you have the number of events and the person-time in each group. For survival analysis you would usually need the observation time for each person. Does that framework fit your scientific problem?

Comment: I can't access individual patient data, so I can't have the exact observation time for each patient, I think I'd have to enter the date as contrast based and not arm-based in my network meta-analysis.

Comment: I am not familiar with setting up for gemtc but can you not use the incidence rate (possibly transformed) for each arm rather than having to use the rate ratio (or some other contrast)?